# RPI as forwarding server

Tags: networking, server

I've just got my RPI and im aiming to use it as a server (forwarding sent chars from android device over wifi to arduino) any ideas how can this work(or at least a part of it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a node.js server (TCP or HTTP) to capture input from your Android over wifi to a serial port where the Arduino is connected.

If your RPi and Arduino are not connected with a cable, you can use BT modules to connect them.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but by using node.js server can i send back data such as video stream from a connected cam to RPI to the android device?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it, but I'd suggest you go with another solution that fits your application better.

Try taking a look at `motion`, it allows you to stream video from a camera attached to the RPi: http://linux.die.net/man/1/motion